Staging ground—suddenly not able to see questions the normal way
All of a sudden, I'm on "staging ground". I commented on a question, but cannot see it the normal way. I don't even know if it is possible to have a link/reference to it.
What is that all about? What am I missing?

Did you see the huge banner on top of SG questions? "Staging Ground is a dedicated space for new askers to receive guidance on improving their questions before they are posted publicly on Stack Overflow." and somesuch? There should be a link to the help center for good measure as well.

@MisterMiyagi so how can I switch back to "normal mode"?

@GyroGearloose What "normal mode"? These questions are in the SG, there is no "normal" twin question outside of SG. The help center article should detail what the SG actually is, and how questions can leave the SG (which shouldn't happen just because you want to answer them).

@MisterMiyagi looks like we are looking at different things. I see https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78773024#comment138887863_78773024 and what I can see there doesn't look like viewing questions as it did 4 weeks ago.

@GyroGearloose read this help center article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground

@GyroGearloose I didn't say SG looks like normal SO (what you probably mean by "doesn't look like viewing questions as it did 4 weeks ago"). SG looks like, well, SG because its entire point is not to be normal SO. If you only want to see "normal" questions, don't look at SG questions; specifically, if you are looking for questions via the main page, avoid the ones that say "Staging Ground" to, well, avoid SG questions. If you want something else, it might help to clearly spell that out and not rely on people guessing what exactly you do-or-do-not know/assume.

@MisterMiyagi so the site has changed in general since 4 weeks ago? That would be an explanation. Is it so? Was there a change in said timeß

@GyroGearloose No, the site didn't change. Instead of me repeating the entire history of SG, I recommend you read through the help pages and search meta for, well, "Staging Ground".

What is the “normal way”? You won’t see a question outside of SG until it’s promoted out of SG.

@KarlKnechtel the proposed duplicate is much too complex IMO, there should be a simple Q for "where did the SG question go?" without extra noise. It's really the company's fault for mixing announcements with usage basic usage info - those make poor dup targets and a mess of an unfocused post.

My guess is you got to the Staging Ground from the questions page. This is what my home page looks like right now:

The first question is a normal one; it's labeled with its votes, answers, and views. But the second question has a "Staging Ground" and "New" labels. These indicate that someone has posted a new question to the Staging Ground, a relatively new feature with a different function.
If you want to go back to actual questions, just take a look at the left-hand sidebar:

There's both a "Question" and "Staging Ground" option - just click the "Questions" one to get back!

So my problem was that the default linking is now to staging ground and I have to do an additional click (and to know that and where to click).

@GyroGearloose What do you mean by "default linking"? The homepage still has both SG and normal questions, and clicking the stackoverflow icon still gets you out of SG back to the homepage. Unless you manually go into SG, you shouldn't end up in SG.

Still there seems to be something wrong. I cannot find my comment that was given on "staging ground". "All actions" does not show it.

@GyroGearloose Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground

@MisterMiyagi I wouldn't have asked if it had worked that way for me.

@GyroGearloose Some questions are labeled as normal. Some are labeled as SG. They are different things. Just don't click on the SG questions if you don't want to deal with SG.

@GyroGearloose If what hadn't worked for you that way? What specifically happens when you do what exactly? Does the address stackoverflow.com lead you to the staging ground instead? Does looking at the homepage only show staging ground questions? Does clicking the stackoverflow icon lead you to the staging ground instead of the homepage?

General reminder you can remove Staging Ground questions from the list in your preferences. Profile > Settings > Preferences > Show Staging Ground questions.

@MisterMiyagi "If what hadn't ..." Well, I clicked on "Questions" and ended on "Staging ground". I first mistakenly thought this had to do with new privileges.

@GyroGearloose Please open a bug report question here on meta that says so clearly. That would definitely be a bug.

@GyroGearloose Consider the -6 votes being for not clearly stating what's wrong. I've never seen a clearly presented bug report being net-downvoted.

@MisterMiyagi If I knew exactly what was wrong, why should I bother to ask a question?

@GyroGearloose Well, what you describe is a bug so you should have an interest reporting it to get it fixed. That requires clearly stating what is broken (i.e. what happens if you do what and what else you expected to happen instead), not knowing what the fix is. For example, "if I click on questions in the side-bar the staging ground is opened. I expected the regular listing of questions instead.". This meta-questions is very unclear about even the situation you are experiencing, which you should be able to describe in any case.

@MisterMiyagi considering the now -8 votes simple question: WHY?

@GyroGearloose To get the bug fixed that is inconveniencing you. Like, what you just described means that fundamental internal links of SO are broken for you. Surely you want to get that fixed?

@GyroGearloose Please stop yelling. If it's a bug, you can write a bug report. Otherwise, just let it lie. It's totally up to you, and nobody is forcing you to do anything.

@MisterMiyagi "means that fundamental internal links of SO are broken for you. Surely you want to get that fixed?" ... not if I'm the only one and with -12 downvotes on that subject. Looks like an active majority is happy on keeping bugs and killing the messenger.

@GyroGearloose An active majority likely doesn't understand that there even is a bug, let alone which. I've had to go through tons of comments to get a somewhat clear picture of just what you are trying to report. Even if only you experience this bug, as long as you clearly describe it a bug report is perfectly fine, and allows other people to test if they perhaps are affected as well.

@MisterMiyagi I guess OP's description misses out some steps, they are probably talking about them being on the question listing and clicking on a question there leading to the staging ground, which is actually working as designed (Assuming they clicked on an SG question).

@AbdulAzizBarkat That doesn’t match that they vehemently disagreed with my description of navigation and said navigating to Questions leads them to SG instead.

@MisterMiyagi the link to questions and Staging Ground is pretty much normal anchor tags, I don't really think Stack Overflow will get that wrong. My guess is either of the following is the case: 1) OP misclicked 2) OP didn't articulate the problem correctly (For example by "I commented on a question, but cannot see it the normal way." they probably mean to say that they can't find their comment in their activity page)

@AbdulAzizBarkat I don’t see a point in speculating. The OP wrote what they wrote. If that misrepresents their situation, they are the only ones that can clarify.

Thanks to Henry Ecker's comment:

General reminder you can remove Staging Ground questions from the list in your preferences. Profile > Settings > Preferences > Show Staging Ground questions.

